# Should boost be installed in /usr/ or /usr/local/ for bitcoin-core?

Tags: bitcoind, bitcoin-core, compiling

When installing `bitcoin-core`, `libbitcoin` or `libbitcoin-explorer` the build requires the C++ `boost` library. Is there any reason why I should prefer to install `boost` in the `/usr/` hierarchy rather than `/usr/local`. Or should I not attempt to link all my C++ projects to the same `boost` build anyway, and link to a seperate `boost` build (of a possibly different versions installed in different locations) for each project?

Answer (score 2):

Libraries should be installed in `/usr/include`.

For Boost, the path to it should be `/usr/include/boost`. That's where the linker would be looking for the libraries.

Otherwise, you may elect to install the libraries in some different directory and symlink it to `/usr/include` anyways.

Comment: Thank you! it seems however that not everyone agrees (e.g. https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1528661). I now have the impression that unless your boost library is coming from a distribution package, it is advised to stick it in `/usr/local/include/boost` and `/usr/local/lib`  rather than in the `/usr/` hierarchy. I'll wait a bit before accepting this answer as the definite truth :)

Comment: This seems like something more suitable at unix stack exchange if we really wanna discuss where is best to install any arbitrary Libs.